# Add default Items in class

Tags: c#

I have a class and want to add some data on construction so i can used it without using database like :

```
public partial class ActionTypeList
{
    public ActionTypeList()
    {
      new ActionTypeList { Id= "2", FName= "hanumanji" };
      new ActionTypeList { Id= "4", FName= "temples" };
      new ActionTypeList { Id= "38", FName= "books" };
      new ActionTypeList { Id= "28", FName= "stories" }; 
    }
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string FName{ get; set; }
}
```

I just given an example, how to do it I don't know.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Your current example will probably have a Stack Overflow :P

Answer (score 2):

If you need some data to work with then you will want to create separate instances outside the class not in it, that is a bad practice. If you truly feel that you must have data in this class then add a static method to get some your default stuff.

```
public partial class ActionType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<ActionType> GetDefaultActionTypes() { 
        return new List<ActionType> {
            new ActionType { Id = "2", FName = "hanumanji" },
            new ActionType { Id = "4", FName = "temples" },
            new ActionType { Id = "28", FName = "books" },
            new ActionType { Id = "38", FName = "stories" },
        };
    }
}
```

You can then use the static method like this

```
var myDefaultActionTypes = ActionType.GetDefaultActionTypes();
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new class `ActionType` and store your items in the `ActionTypeList`:

```
public class ActionType {

  public ActionType() {
  }

  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string FName { get; set; }

}

public class ActionTypeList : List<ActionType> {

  public ActionTypeList() {
    Add(new ActionType() { Id = "2", FName = "hanumanji" });
    Add(new ActionType { Id = "4", FName = "temples" });
    Add(new ActionType { Id = "38", FName = "books" });
    Add(new ActionType { Id = "28", FName = "stories" });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a static method inside of your class

```
public static List<ActionTypeList> GetActionTypes()
{
   return new List<ActionTypeList> 
   {
       new ActionTypeList { Id= "2", FName= "hanumanji" };
       new ActionTypeList { Id= "4", FName= "temples" };
       new ActionTypeList { Id= "38", FName= "books" };
       new ActionTypeList { Id= "28", FName= "stories" };
   }
}
```

And whenever you want to get your sample list you can call this method.

```
var list = ActionTypeList.GetActionTypes();
```